# Is there a way to get ioredis instance from nestjs-redis client?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, nestjs, ioredis

I'm using the [Nestjs Redis](https://github.com/kyknow/nestjs-redis) component and that component use [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) Node Redis client library. What happens is that I want to save geoinformation through [GEOADD](https://redis.io/commands/geoadd) command available on Redis and available also in the ioredis.

So, how can I get an ioredis instance from Nestjs-Redis component? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `getClient()` method on the `RedisService` instance, that is supposed to do exactly what you need. It returns `ioredis` Redis instance. Please, take a look at it [here](https://github.com/kyknow/nestjs-redis/blob/master/dist/redis.service.d.ts#L6).

So, you have to inject `RedisService` into your service and call the `getClient()` method on the created instance (also, this method accepts a connection name in case you want to get a specific Redis connection).

I'm just curiuos about, do you intentionally use a forked version of the original `nestjs-redis` [package](https://github.com/skunight/nestjs-redis#readme)?

Comment: When I get this instance from `getClient()` doesn't work the call to `geoAdd()`; there isn't this method in that forked version you mentioned...but I really don't why we've used this forked version...we solve this using directly an instance from `ioredis` ! Thanks a lot by your response and sorry by my late reply! :)